# Java/C# Program accessing Oracle database, bad char in string

Tags: java, oracle, character-encoding

I've got the following string in Oracle (the hex dump is right underneath it). As you can see, right after the first "N", there's a bogus character the "0xA6". My Oracle instance is using AL32UTF8 as the character encoding.

```
FLOREN�PALACE HOTEL LTDA   
Typ=1 Len=26: 46,4c,4f,52,45,4e,a6,41,20,50,41,4c,41,43,45,20,48,4f,54,45,4c,20,4c,54,44,41
```

I have two services that are supposed to process this string - one in C# and another in Java. I'm processing this string in C# and it says that the length is 27. I then try to process this string in Java and it says that the length is 25. When I print in C#, it prints (note the A and space before PALACE)

```
FLOREN�A PALACE HOTEL LTDA
```

while in Java it prints the same as Oracle.

When I select the string from Oracle in the Java program, it's like Java is "eating" the 0xA6 and the following two characters after it and counting that as one character. I presume that Java thinks that it's a UTF-8 character (that's the Charset) and so it's consuming the "A" and " " after the "0xA6".

Is there a way that I can make Java a little less aggressive when it comes to grouping the "A" and " " with the "0xA6"?

Any suggestions appreciated,

mj

EDIT 0

I've looked at the code that fetches the string from Oracle. I'm using the Oracle JDBC driver like so.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");  
m_connection = DriverManager.getConnection(m_connectionString, m_username, m_password);
```

My connection string is

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.0.18:1521/serviceName
```

With respect to actually fetching the string from the database, I've used the ResultSet getBytes, getString, getBinaryStream, getUnicodeStream calls. Looking at the bytes in a byte[], char[], or string shows me strange bytes in the 0xA6, "A", and " " positions (0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD) when I use getBytes for example.

/EDIT 0

Comment: How are you doing the hex dump at the top? From a program that reads from the database, or somehow from the database command prompt itself?

Comment: I'm using SQLDeveloper and running the following SQL: select foo, dump(foo,16) from my_table

Comment: How are you retrieving/processing the string, particularly in Java; might be helpful to show the code from pulling it from the DB to when you get the length/print it. And, maybe, your locale. Some reproducible code would be nice, if that's practical. Can you examine it char by char in a StringBuffer, or retrieve it as a byte array from the DB? To maybe help isolate if JDBC is confused, or something afterwards. Is it `VARCHAR2` or `NVARCHAR2` in the DB? (Sorry for so many questions, just dumping thoughts...!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like data corruption.  Likely the original data was encoded in ISO-8859 and not converted to UTF-8.

`0xA6` by itself in ISO-8859-1 is the "broken vertical bar" `¦` character, which doesn't make sense,

*BUT*,

in ***ISO-8859-2*** it is equivalent to Unicode 0x015A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH ACUTE), or Ś, which looks likely.  It makes the whole string *FLORENŚA PALACE HOTEL LTDA*

The solution is to replace that character with the proper UTF-8 encoding, which would be `0xc5 0x9a`

Comment: I agree that this is corrupt. The problem is, I need the string in the Java program to look exactly the same as it does in the C# program. I'm storing and sharing character indexes across the two programs and this misalignment is not helping.

Comment: You have non-UTF8 data stored in a database that's telling the client code it _is_ UTF8.  This will result in undefined behavior depending on how the clients are implemented.  You cannot write code for this guaranteed to work now, or at any point in the future if either driver vendor makes changes to how invalid UTF8 is handled.  The only real solution is to fix the data encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string `convert(your_string, 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P2')` before passing it to Java.

Comment: When using WE8ISO8859P2 I get an error "unsupported character set". I tried WE8ISO8859P1 and WE8ISO8859P15 and both of those gave me something.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, while trying to implement one of the suggestions above, I discovered that the OJDBC driver was the culprit in that is was changing encodings on me. In order to preserve the encoding so I could remove bad characters, I used the following SQL.

select utl_raw.cast_to_raw( col ) from tab;

I then iterated through the bytes and squashed the bogus character.